# По каким причинам может отваливаться примонтированная директория?

Tags: python, linux, сеть, smb

Есть директория, которая монтируется к серверу, по каким-то причинам она отваливается на чтение, хотя если я физический зайду на сервер, то я вижу и папку и файлы. Чтобы снова появился доступ на чтение необходимо только перемонтировать директорию. В папке находятся изображения около 10 гб.
Подскажите кто сталкивался с чем-то подобным, хочу попробовать воспроизвести эту ошибку, может есть у кого советы куда копать. Сам я в этом большой профан, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.
Если это поможет: с папкой взаимодействует приложение на питоне, которое ходит туда и забирает нужное изображение + выводит его на печать.Директория примонтирована по протоколу SMB

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу выяснить почему к директории пропадает доступ на чтение

Comment: например, отваливается сеть. или у сервера есть ограничение на кол-во одновременных подключений и их всех занимают. И получается, что ничего не отваливается, просто нет свободного места.

Comment: Спасибо, @KoVadim, попробую проверить